# Assigning values to raster obtained form scanned map using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, mapping, paper

I scanned a temperature map for a specific region and I would like that the raster pixels had the original values from the paper map so I can do further analysis (for example, difference of temperature between time periods). I have tried to find an answer in the Google and Qgis documentation, but did not have luck.

This is the map:

[image]